# Extracting SWF/Flash link from String - Regular Expression

Tags: regex, vb.net, flash, extract

I made this code :

```
^http:.*.swf$
```

to extract swf link from string : **starting** from http and **ending** in swf

is it ideal ? or are there better rules to do that ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that it will always start and end with that, it's fine but make sure you escape (`\`) the dot.

```
^http:.*?\.swf$
```

Comment: thank you , if you look at this example [link](http://regexr.com/38p1b)
it will also include text between two links while I want it to start only from http , how can we improve it ?

Comment: Just remove the `^` and `$` anchors and add the `?` quantifier. See [`here`](http://regexr.com/38p1h)

Comment: how about getting swf from param tag & embed tag?